# AWS CDK - circular dependency when adding IAM Profile to Launch Template

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to build `LaunchTemplate` using AWS CDK (I want to use it with ASG later) and I need to specify `iam_instance_profile`. Unfortunately, when I do so it crashes with circular dependency.

My first attempt was to pick the role that gets built by `add_auto_scaling_group_capacity` method (it constructs ASG with `LaunchConfiguration` instead of `LaunchTemplate` so I can't use it for spot fleet):

instance_

```
profile = nodegroup_resource.node.find_child("InstanceProfile")
launch_template = aws_ec2.CfnLaunchTemplate(
            self.cluster, "launch_template",
            launch_template_data = aws_ec2.CfnLaunchTemplate.LaunchTemplateDataProperty(
                (...)
                # circural dependency
                iam_instance_profile=instance_profile
            )
        )
```

This fails with

```
Error: Resolution error: Resolution error: Unable to resolve object tree with circular reference. Path: /Resources/${Token[eks-staging.Staging.launch_template.LogicalID.1848]}/Properties/launchTemplateData/iamInstanceProfile/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host..
    at resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-JNb7BY/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.js:35:15)
    at Object.resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-JNb7BY/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.js:29:33)
    at resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-JNb7BY/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.js:118:43)
```

So I tried to skip adding profile on construction, explicitly adding dependency and then adding profile:

```
launch_template = aws_ec2.CfnLaunchTemplate(
            self.cluster, "launch_template",
            launch_template_data = aws_ec2.CfnLaunchTemplate.LaunchTemplateDataProperty(
                (...)
                # circural dependency
                # iam_instance_profile=instance_profile
            )
        )
launch_template.add_depends_on(instance_profile)
launch_template.add_property_override('iam_instance_profile', instance_profile)
```

This also fails but with slightly different error:

```
RangeError: Resolution error: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
    at deepMerge (/tmp/jsii-kernel-QQgBdo/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/cfn-resource.js:1:1)
    at deepMerge (/tmp/jsii-kernel-QQgBdo/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/cfn-resource.js:409:17)
    at deepMerge (/tmp/jsii-kernel-QQgBdo/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/cfn-resource.js:409:17)
    at deepMerge (/tmp/jsii-kernel-QQgBdo/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/cfn-resource.js:409:17)
    at deepMerge (/tmp/jsii-kernel-QQgBdo/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/cfn-resource.js:409:17)
    at deepMerge (/tmp/jsii-kernel-QQgBdo/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/cfn-resource.js:409:17)
    at deepMerge (/tmp/jsii-kernel-QQgBdo/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/cfn-resource.js:409:17)
    at deepMerge (/tmp/jsii-kernel-QQgBdo/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/cfn-resource.js:409:17)
    at deepMerge (/tmp/jsii-kernel-QQgBdo/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/cfn-resource.js:409:17)
    at deepMerge (/tmp/jsii-kernel-QQgBdo/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/cfn-resource.js:409:17)
```

I thought it could be some problem with the way `InstanceProfile` was built in the first place so I tried to build another object with the same role attached:

```
role = nodegroup_resource.node.find_child('InstanceRole')
instance_profile = aws_iam.CfnInstanceProfile(self.cluster, "instance_profile", roles=[role.role_arn])
```

Unfortunately, it didn't help and errors are the same.

How can I solve it? Or at least how to debug the exact issue?

Comment: I found a TypeScript example that might be adapted to Python to fit your case: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3077#issue-460797384 Basically, what you need to do is to create the Role first, then create the CfnInstanceRole and then refer to the ARN (not the Construct itself) inside the CfnLaunchTemplate. In this way, you only get a one way dependency between the three Constructs.

Comment: Yeah, I was basing on this example in the first place. What I wanted to avoid was creation of new Role. Instead I tried to pick the role created for ASG with LaunchTemplate so that it would have exactly same permissions without need for handling them manually...

Comment: You could always inspect the original source code that generates that role and replicate it.

Comment: If you add `spot_price="{your bid here}"` to the ASG then it will use SPOT. But this is only if you want spot-only fleet. If you need mixed then yes - one needs a launch template.